# Rails ajax form with join table associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a 'ajaxy' form between two models in rails. here are the relevant files and code snippets...

## my models

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140214134314) do

  create_table "group_shots", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "shot_id"
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "groups", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "shots", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

end
```

## app/views/groups/show.html.erb

```
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @group.name %>
<%= link_to 'New Shot', new_shot_path, id: "new_shot", remote: true %></br>
```

## app/views/shots/new.js.erb

```
$('#new_shot').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

## app/controllers/shots_controller.rb

```
 def create
    @shot = Shot.new(params[:shot])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shot.save
        GroupShot.create! :shot_id => @shot.id

 def new
    @shot = Shot.new
 end
```

My end goals is when a user is viewing a group (show action/view) that they can add a shot that is associated with that group, and consequently when the user adds the shot, the correct entries are made in the group_shot table.

You can see in the shots controller, when the shot is saved I am creating a new entry in the group/shots table successfully. I am getting the shot_id, but not the group_id. So that is the question, how do I get the group_id in this view/controller. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to pass the group_id as a parameter to the call to new_shot_path in your groups_controller#show view:

```
new_shot_path(group_id: @group)
```

then include it as a hidden field in the form you're using in your shots_controller#new view, using hidden_field_tag:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'group_id', @group.id %>
```

and then include it in your call to GroupShot#create in the shots_controller#create method:

```
GroupShot.create! :shot_id => @shot.id, :group_id => params[:group_id]
```

Just keep in mind that you're doing two things in shots_controller#create -- both creating the shot and associating it back to the group, which is perhaps a little unorthodox.  From your code, it appears that a Shot is never created without an associated Group.  If your starting point is always from viewing groups (then adding shots to a selected group), you may want to consider moving this to the groups_controller as something like #add_shot, but that's going to be depend on how the rest of your application is architected.

Comment: Thanks guys, I don't this is going to work. Note while this in the groups view, all of the logic is happening in the shots_controller, but cause thats where the ajax/partials are being called from. The group has already been created, I just need to somehow get the id.

Comment: Then I think you're going to have to pass it as a param in the call to new_shot_path in groups/show.html -- `new_shot_path(group_id: @group)`. But I believe you will have to modify the route to recognize the parameter if you do this.

Comment: Thats a good call, and definitely gets me closer. Here is what I have now http://pastie.org/8734318. I am able to create @group in the new action, but this does not persist over to create. I am going to keep looking at it. So close!!!

Comment: @group won't carry over automatically. You have to pass it from the 'new' form to 'create' - I usually do this with a hidden_field_tag.  In the form you're using in 'new' add a hidden_form_tag, name it group_id and give it the value of @group.id.  Then, in your show#create method, pull it out of the params hash `group_id = params[:group_id]`.  In your call to GroupShot.create, replace `:group_id => @group.id` with `:group_id => group_id`

Comment: Wow...this is terrible. I feel like a need to go take a shower. Here is what I ended up with: http://pastie.org/8734492 This feels dirty. Does ajax always feel this dirty in rails?

Comment: Well, using hidden fields always feels a little unclean to me, but bear in mind you're really doing 2 things in the Shot#new method - creating the new shot and associating it with a group -- that's why you're having to do something unorthodox with the hidden field.  Doing this straight from the groups_controller with something like #add_shot would probably be cleaner, but it sounds like you have implementation reasons to not want to do that.

Comment: OK thanks. My ajax and js stink, so its a learning process. This was just a test app to experiment with. Hopefully my implementation in my production app will be cleaner. If you want to edit your answer above I will accept it. Thanx for the help!